# Hotkey to open specific app window (MS Teams)

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys, microsoft-teams

Is there a way to set up a hotkey in windows 10 to un-minimize a specific app window? The app I want to do it (MS Teams) is already running in background.

I did assign a shortcut key to it

[image]

but for some reason it works very slow - bringing the window to from takes around 10 seconds, whereas if I click on the icon in the task bar, it's instant - so it cannot be a 'slow PC lag'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To un-minimize the windows of a specific application, you may use the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script uses <kbd>F12</kbd> key to un-minimize the windows of
`notepad.exe`:

```
F12::WinActivate, ahk_exe notepad.exe
```

AutoHotKey is very versatile and many adaptations of the above command
are possible.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [WinActivate](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm)
- [The WinTitle Parameter](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm)
- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)

Comment: For Microsoft Teams this is ahk_exe Teams.exe

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put activate Microsoft Teams Main window you can also have a look at [Teamsy](https://tdalon.github.io/ahk/Teamsy).
It is also offered compiled so you can run it without installing AutoHotkey.

The main code doing this looks like:

```
Teams_GetMainWindow(){
; See implementation explanations here: https://tdalon.blogspot.com/get-teams-window-ahk
; Syntax: hWnd := Teams_GetMainWindow()

WinGet, WinCount, Count, ahk_exe Teams.exe

If (WinCount = 0)
    GoTo, StartTeams

If (WinCount = 1) {
    TeamsMainWinId := WinExist("ahk_exe Teams.exe")
    return TeamsMainWinId
}

; Get main window via Acc Window Object Name
WinGet, id, List,ahk_exe Teams.exe
Loop, %id%
{
    hWnd := id%A_Index%
    oAcc := Acc_Get("Object","4",0,"ahk_id " hWnd)
    sName := oAcc.accName(0)
    If RegExMatch(sName,".* \| Microsoft Teams, Main Window$") {
        return hWnd
    }
}

; Fallback solution with minimize all window and run exe
If WinActive("ahk_exe Teams.exe") {
    GroupAdd, TeamsGroup, ahk_exe Teams.exe
    WinMinimize, ahk_group  TeamsGroup
} 

StartTeams: 
fTeamsExe = C:\Users\%A_UserName%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe
If !FileExist(fTeamsExe) {
    return
}

Run, %fTeamsExe%
WinWaitActive, ahk_exe Teams.exe
TeamsMainWinId := WinExist("A")
PowerTools_RegWrite("TeamsMainWinId",TeamsMainWinId)
return TeamsMainWinId

} ; eofun
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/tdalon/84d9caea0368ab0420b81363c2048705

To do what you want then simply call

```
WinId := Teams_GetMainWindow()
WinActivate, ahk_id %WinId%
```

and you can bind it to any hotkey, example for F12

```
F12::
WinId := Teams_GetMainWindow()
WinActivate, ahk_id %WinId% 
return
```